# PyTorch model evaluation crashes with error c0000374 in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, pytorch, unreal-engine4, libtorch

This PyTorch model evaluation crashes with error c0000374 in Unreal Engine.

The same code is working without any issues on regular desktop App. 
Model is loaded from content folder of Plugin:

```
auto model_path = FPaths::Combine(*BaseDir, TEXT("Content/model.pt"));
module = torch::jit::load(TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*model_path));
```

Error appears on evaluation:

```
auto output = module.forward(inputs);
```

Output window log:

> 'UE4Editor.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\projects\MyProject\Plugins\MyPlugin\Binaries\ThirdParty\MyPluginLibrary\Win64\torch_cpu.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols.
>
> 'UE4Editor.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcomp140.dll'.
>
> Critical error detected c0000374
>
> UE4Editor.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Comment: Could you check whether the model is correctly loaded? You may wrap it with `std::shared_ptr` (e.g. via `std::make_shared`) and check for `nullptr`.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Thank you for replay. As I understand torch::jit::script::Module itself is a reference and hence `std::hared_ptr` could not be created for it. The `module.type()` method seems returns an `std::shared_ptr` to base class and it is not `nullptr`. Also I tried to wrap it into try, cath:

`try {
 module = torch::jit::load(TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*model_path));
 }
 catch (const c10::Error& e) {
  (void)e;
  FMessageDialog::Open(EAppMsgType::Ok, FText::FromString("Module is not loaded"));
 }`
it works without issues.